# How do I create a second header in alertdialog in android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I would like to have this alertdialog, but with a second header to split the following list in two.

[This is how the alertdialog current looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aj6E.jpg)

Here is the code:

```
final CharSequence[] items = {" Cereal ", " Chocolate chips ", " Crunchy peanut butter ", " Vanilla ", " Espresso powder ",
            " Kosher salt ", " Powdered sugar ", " Marshmallows "};
    // arraylist to keep the selected items
    final ArrayList seletedItems = new ArrayList();

    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Ingredients List");
    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items, null,
            new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                // indexSelected contains the index of item (of which checkbox checked)
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int indexSelected,
                                    boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        // If the user checked the item, add it to the selected items
                        // write your code when user checked the checkbox
                        seletedItems.add(indexSelected);
                    } else if (seletedItems.contains(indexSelected)) {
                        // Else, if the item is already in the array, remove it
                        // write your code when user Uchecked the checkbox
                        seletedItems.remove(Integer.valueOf(indexSelected));
                    }
                }
            })
            // Set the action buttons
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    //  Your code when user clicked on OK
                    //  You can write the code  to save the selected item here

                }
            });
    dialog = builder.create();
```

Comment: This would require a custom `Dialog`. `AlertDialog` is pretty much used as a convenience method to make commonly used `Dialog` objects with common looks and feels.

Answer (score 0):

AlertDialog can not have second header but You can create it in content View of dialog, to set content View use:

```
 dialog.setContentView(R.layout.your_content_view);
```

In layout **R.layout.your_content_view** You can have any structure, so it is possible to add there TextView which will look like header.

Do set header text just:

```
 TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.header);
 text.setText("Header text");
```

of course **R.id.header** must exists in **R.layout.your_content_view**

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction and I figured it out. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem @WesleySmith if it no problem for You - vote for answer and check it is right. Thanks!